# Java 8 way to convert collection into one key multiple values map

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8

Any way to perform the below code using Java 8.

```
        final Map<String, Collection<ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel>> attributeRulesMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel>>();
        for (final ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel rule : rules)
        {
            final String key = rule.getProductStrAttributeOverride().getProductStrTypeField().getAttributeDescriptorQualifier();
            if (attributeRulesMap.containsKey(key))
            {
                final Collection<ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel> currentRules = attributeRulesMap.get(key);
                currentRules.add(rule);
            }
            else
            {
                final Collection<ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel> list = new LinkedList<ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel>();
                list.add(rule);
                attributeRulesMap.put(key, list);
            }
        }
```

if it is only

```
 final Map<String, ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel> attributeRulesMap
```

than i can do like following but i need to arrange the whole collection inside a map based on key and each key can have multiple values stored in collection.

```
Map<String, ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel> result =
choices.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel::getProductStrAttributeOverride.getProductStrTypeField.getAttributeDescriptorQualifier,
                                          Function.identity()));
```

Comment: For pre Java 8 code, this is a bit of an antipattern. You use two map lookups (`containsKey` and `get`) when you could simply use one. This makes the code potentially a whole lot slower.

Comment: You mentioned a nice point Boris. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BoristheSpider If there is a pair `("something", null)`, `containsKey("something")` will return `true`, but `get("something")` will return `null` - the same result as if there was no such key at all.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I know how a `Map` works. In this instance, the logic is identical so it is not required - it is a waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: @Jaroslaw Pawlak: it should be obvious that it would *not* be helpful here, if a present mapping to `null` is treated as “present”, as per `containsKey`, when a `Collection` is expected to which an element will be unconditionally added. The cases where a mapping to `null` really needs to be respected are rare and even then, it’s more efficient to say `value=map.get(key); if(value==null && !map.containsKey(key)) …`.

Comment: @Holger I really have no idea where these ideas for premature optimisations are coming from. This is a hash map, it has constant access time which on average is instant. Is this code slow? Have you run the profiler on it? Is reading from the map the slowest bit? Of course it's 3 times no. And performance is not even what OP asked about.

Comment: @Jaroslaw Pawlak: It isn’t premature optimization to avoid double work. A hash lookup has constant time, but it doesn’t come for free. And it’s not that we were talking about adding a complicated trick, we were talking about making the code *simpler* by removing an unnecessary check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `groupingBy` :

```
Map<String,List<ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel>>
    map = 
        choices.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(rule -> rule.getProductStrAttributeOverride().getProductStrTypeField().getAttributeDescriptorQualifier()));
```

And if you don't want a `List`, you can pass a second argument to `groupingBy` and specify whatever `Collection` you want. For example :

```
Map<String,Collection<ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel>>
    map =
        choices.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(rule -> rule.getProductStrAttributeOverride().getProductStrTypeField().getAttributeDescriptorQualifier(),
                                              Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)));
```

Comment: final Map<String, List<ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel>> map = rules.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    rule -> rule.getProductStrAttributeOverride().getProductStrTypeField().getAttributeDescriptorQualifier())); gives me the following error Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,List<Object>> to Map<String,List<ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel>>

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Does the `getAttributeDescriptorQualifier()` method return a `String`?

Comment: final String key = rule.getProductStrAttributeOverride().getProductStrTypeField().getAttributeDescriptorQualifier(); i posted in the code also

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Perhaps it's some compiler issue. Try `rule -> (String) rule.getProductStrAttributeOverride().getProductStrTypeField().getAttributeDescriptorQualifier()`. BTW, are `choices` and `rules` of the same type? Your first snippet uses a `rules` collection while the second uses `choices`.

Comment: One last question what should i do if i want to change the code to currentRules.add(new StringAttributeOverrideValueGetter(rule)); ofcourse now the collection inside Map is of type StringAttributeOverrideValueGetter

Comment: @SaurabhKumar use a `mapping` Collector to map the objects from one type to another : ...collect(Collectors.groupingBy(rule -> rule.getProductStrAttributeOverride().getProductStrTypeField().getAttributeDescriptorQualifier(),Collectors.mapping(StringAttributeOverrideValueGetter::new,Collectors.toList())));

Comment: Perfect @Eran. Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 1):

Note that it doesn’t always have to be a `Stream` operation. Your code would also benefit from using the “diamond operator” (though not new to Java 8) and from using new collection operations, i.e. `computeIfAbsent`, which allows to elide the entire conditional inside the loop and its code duplication. Putting both together, you’ll get:

```
final Map<String, Collection<ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel>>
                                                   attributeRulesMap = new HashMap<>();
for(final ProductStrAttributeOverrideRulesModel rule: rules)
{
    final String key = rule.getProductStrAttributeOverride()
        .getProductStrTypeField().getAttributeDescriptorQualifier();
    attributeRulesMap.computeIfAbsent(key, x->new LinkedList<>()).add(rule);
}
```

You could also replace the loop by a `forEach` invocation, if you wish:

```
rules.forEach(rule -> attributeRulesMap.computeIfAbsent(
    rule.getProductStrAttributeOverride()
        .getProductStrTypeField().getAttributeDescriptorQualifier(),
    x->new LinkedList<>()).add(rule)
);
```

though it’s debatable whether this is an improvement over the classical loop here…